# Django with Docker error 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'

Tags: python, django, docker

I have an app in which I use Django authentication. When I use it locally with classic
`python manage.py runserver`
All works fine, but when I try to run it from docker I get a TypeError
`Exception Value:    argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath`
Which is triggering from this piece of code in my template
`{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

And then I get this error,
`During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:`

my view.py file

```
# Create your views here.     
def target_first_page(request):
    return render(request, "target/target_main.html")

@login_required
def target_survey(request):
    return render(request, "target/target_survey.html")

@login_required
def target_survey_result(request):
    return render(request, "target/target_survey_result.html")
```

Any idea what happening here?

Comment: Can you share your view file? thank you